# How to set and access session in EE?

Tags: templates, sessions

SEE: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/224965/

I need to display something to the user only once. How do I do this in the templates? My idea is to store a value in session and use it to decide whether to output this something or not. Any ideas what I should do in EE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native way to store session information, but there is an add-on, [Session Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/session-variables-plugin), which does exactly what you're looking for.